# What is good way to call out the sub fields in rest api call

Tags: api, rest

I was trying to decide what is good way to  call out the sub fields in API design.

Take example of following object.

Eg.

```
<Car>
  <Name/>
  <Type/>
  <Components>
    <count>1</count>
    <Wheel>
      <Location></Location>
      <Brand></Brand>
    </Wheel>
  </Components>
</Car>
```

?fields=name,Components :group(Components :Count,Wheel:group(Wheel :Location,brand))

or

?fields= name,Components.Count,Components.Wheel.Location,Components.Wheel.Brand

Does any one know what are best practices here?

Comment: How would a client know how to use this query parameters? There is nothing in the `Car` representation that tells him that there even is a `fields` parameter.

Comment: That would be part of specs published.

Comment: That is not very RESTful. A key concept of REST is [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS).